# Llamar sp de FireBird desde C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, firebird2.5

tengo el siguiente problema. Siempre he usado sql pero en un proyecto en el que estoy necesito usar FireBird 2.5, el problema que tengo es que no sé usarlo y tampoco sé llamarlo correctamente en C#, en mi proyecto de WinForms. Les dejo abajo el código del sp que tengo y el de C# que uso para llamarlo.

Es un SP de una sentencia de insert.

```
create or alter procedure INSERTAR_PAGA_M01
as
declare variable IMPORTE integer;
declare variable FOLIO varchar(10);
declare variable TIPO_MOV varchar(10);
declare variable FECHA date;
declare variable CVE_PROV varchar(10);
begin
  INSERT INTO PAGA_M01 (CVE_PROV, REFER, NUM_CARGO, NUM_CPTO, DOCTO, IMPORTE, FECHA_APLI, TCAMBIO, TIPO_MOV)
              VALUES(:cve_prov, :folio, 1, 1, :folio, :importe, :fecha, 1, :tipo_mov);
  suspend;
end
```

Desde mi código lo mando ejecutar y le mando las variables de la siguiente forma:

```
using(FbConnection cone = new FbConnection(GBEmpresa.GlobalEA.cadenaConexion))
        {
            cone.Open();
            FbCommand command = new FbCommand();
            command.Connection = cone;
            command.CommandText = "EXECUTE PROCEDURE INSERTAR_PAGA_M01";
            command.Parameters.Add("@FOLIO", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = xml.Folio;
            command.Parameters.Add("@FECHA", FbDbType.Date).Value = xml.Fecha;
            command.Parameters.Add("@CVE_PROV", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = xml.RfcEmisor;
            command.Parameters.Add("@IMPORTE", FbDbType.Float).Value = xml.Importe;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TIPO_MOV", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = xml.Serie;
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            cone.Close();
        }
```

Actualización, cambié un poco la sintaxis pero no funcionó, me da este error:

Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -204\r\nProcedure unknown\r\nINSERTAR_PAGA_M01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reemplaza:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE INSERTAR_PAGA_M01
```

Por:

```
INSERTAR_PAGA_M01
```

En `command.CommandText`  siempre va el nombre con el cual se ha creado el procedimiento almacenado.

Lectura sugerida: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/modifying-data-with-stored-procedures