# Error Token Invalido -104 FireBird

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firebird

IscException: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 53
09

Me tira esto cuando corro mi sp:

```
using(FbConnection cone = new FbConnection(GBEmpresa.GlobalEA.cadenaConexion))
        {
            cone.Open();
            FbCommand command = new FbCommand();
            command.Connection = cone;
            command.CommandText = "EXECUTE PROCEDURE INSERTAR_PAGA_M01('"+xml.Serie+"', "+xml.Fecha+", "+xml.Importe+", '"+xml.Folio+"', '"+xml.RfcEmisor+"')";
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            cone.Close();
        }
```

¿Hice algo mal?

Perdonen si es algo muy simple pero no he usado firebird y es la primera vez que trabajo con él entonces no entiendo bien su sintaxis ni mucho menos los errores que regresa.

Les dejo el sp por si está mal algo:

```
create or alter procedure INSERTAR_PAGA_M01
as
declare variable IMPORTE integer;
declare variable FOLIO varchar(10);
declare variable TIPO_MOV varchar(10);
declare variable FECHA date;
declare variable CVE_PROV varchar(10);
declare variable NEW_VAR integer;
begin
  INSERT INTO PAGA_M01 (CVE_PROV, REFER, NUM_CARGO, NUM_CPTO, DOCTO, IMPORTE, FECHA_APLI, TCAMBIO, TIPO_MOV)
              VALUES(:cve_prov, :folio, 1, 1, :folio, :importe, :fecha, 1, :tipo_mov);
  suspend;
end
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47376271/3613462

Comment: Creo que te di respuesta en [Llamar sp de FireBird desde C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/569079/llamar-sp-de-firebird-desde-c/579472#579472)